# how to use intellij-leiningen-plugin in intellij idea 14

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen

I don't know how to use `leiningen` plugin in *IntellJ Idea14*.

I have tried 2 ways:

1. I have downloaded from http://github.com/derkork/intellij-leiningen-plugin

and now how to use it

2. I have installed in config/plugins/Browse Repositories 
   but when I create new project

I can't see any `leiningen` project?
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: The IntelliJ Leiningen Plugin is abandoned. You should look out for an other one. I can highly recommend [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/). This one has also Leiningen support.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin has been unmaintained for a long time. It's officially been replaced by [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/), whose lein support was initially based on the source code from this plugin. It was generously donated by the plugin authors.